# How to store wordpress functions (wp_head(),wp_footer()) in a javascript variable?

Tags: wp-head

how to store `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` in a javascript variable ?

```
   var s = '';
   <?php ob_start();
   wp_head();
   wp_footer();
   $string = ob_get_contents();
   ob_end_clean();
   var ss = '<?php echo $string;?>';
```

am using an editor, I want to get this `wp_head()`inside of that editor for getting the proper styles of 'products' that wordpress used.

can anyone please suggest some way to do it ?

Comment: The `wp_head()` function is a wrapper for `do_action('wp_head');
`. Shoving everything returned by those actions into a string is going to for sure cause some kind of issue, if it's possible at all.

Comment: Perhaps if you describe your ultimate objective and why you decided to try your proposed solution, then people can advise other ways.  Personally I'm struggling to imagine why one would need to do this in js.